# Appending a hash '#' symbol to url with a form action?

Tags: javascript, forms

So I've got a form with a submit button and a text input...

I want:
http://localhost/

to become:
http://localhost/#q=

I did a solution in javascript which involves changing the "action" of the form to the url with the hash onclick.. but this doesn't work in IE.

Anyone have a solution that works on all browsers?

Answer (score 9):

I ran into a similar problem with IE not pulling in the hash from the form action.

I had a form

```
<form action="/#search" id="search-form">
   <input type="text" class="search-query" placeholder="Search" name="q">
</form>
```

When I submitted this form in anything but IE the page went to

`/?q=searchparams#search`

But in IE it went to

`/?q=searchparams`

To solve this I used JQuery to bind to the submit action and redirect to the page I wanted it to go to.

```
$("#search-form").submit(function() {
    var query = $('input[name="q"]').val();
    window.location.href = 'index.php?q='+query+'#search';
    return false;
});
```

It's been working fine since.

Comment: I ran in to a similar issue in IE. We ended up url encoding the `#` to `%23`.  This allowed us to submit the form normally and keep the hash.

Comment: @KevinM that's effectively the correct answer. It means the whole thing can work as intended across the board without conditional code or a script dependency. You should submit it as an answer in its own right! (or I will :P)

Answer (score 7):

```
<script>
function add_hash() {
    window.location.hash = "q=";
}    
</script>

<form onsubmit="add_hash(); return false;">
```

Not sure what you're doing with this, though.

Comment: Most likely some kind of search or lookup system, something like google does.