# Simple html page search

Tags: html, search

http://torasbo.se/lumos/blog20.html contains a simple search form.

```
<form class="searchform" method="get">
    <input type="text" id="s2" name="s" value="type and hit enter" onfocus="this.value=''" onblur="this.value='type and hit enter'"/>
</form>
```

If I enter - *Benjamin* - nothing is found and the file bar shows `blog20.html?s=Benjamin`.

If I alter the file bar to `blog20.html?s=#Benjamin` then the search is sucessful.

What do I have to change to accomplish this? I have spent 3 days searching and found nothing.

Comment: When you typing blog20.html?s=#Benjamin in address bar, this meaning search nothing (s=) and go to Benjamin id (#Benjamin).

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203856/appending-a-hash-symbol-to-url-with-a-form-action or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542265/changing-an-url-hash-from-a-form-submit

Comment: You could always use JS for this, but that wouldn't be worth it. You should be using `#` *(Hash) * in the url string

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have JQuery on your site. Add this in the header of you page after JQuery is called.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.searchform').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var object = $(this).find('input');
            window.location.hash = object.val();
            object.blur();
        });
    });
</script>
```

It blocks the default action of the search form, and instead pushes the hash header to your page. Using a more complete search system would work better and make searches more flexible, but this is what you were evidently trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Paste this code in your file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var submitClicked = false;
        $(".searchform").submit(function(e){
            if(submitClicked === false){
                e.preventDefault();
                var searchString = "#"+$("#s2").val();
                submitClicked = true;
                window.location = window.location.href+"?s="+searchString;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```